# Eclipse shows different then when I debug on my phone

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, debugging, sdk

This is what eclipse shows me in the editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjwu9.png

This is what it looks like when I run it on my phone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6NG5.png

This is the code im using.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_button"

        android:text="Settings" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24dp"  android:textColor="#000000" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the settings to be in the center. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Settings" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24dp"  android:textColor="#000000" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That makes no sense. Post your entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_gravity is used to set the gravity of the View or Layout relative to its parent.

For the button element add
`android:layout_gravity="center"`
This should make it centered.

Also, not sure but its possible that you're getting different results because of the chosen  text size...try a smaller/bigger size and check if the results vary.

Comment: I added android:layout_gravity="center" and changed the font but it still is not centered on my phone.

Comment: Ok sorry. In your Linear Layout instead of `android:gravity="bottom"` make it `center`

Comment: I tried it but the "Settings" text is still not in the center. Also I used android:gravity="bottom" because I want the bottom at the bottom of the screen. The text is centered in the Graphical Layout but when I run it on my phone its on the left.